# Adding Controls Dynamically inside a gridview and retrieving its values entered by user in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am using Asp.Net Gridview inside which there are 2 columns. First Column has a dropdown and depending on the selection I am dynamically adding a control inside second column like it may be a `TextBox`, `Dropdown` ,etc. This is working fine. Now if i want to retrieve the value from that `TextBox` entered by the user what can I do?

Comment: You should show your code/markup, so that whoever is answering doesn't have to guess at what you done. It's too ambiguous to just describe what you've done.

Comment: The cleanest approach would be to encapsulate all controls in a `UserControl` where all possible controls are `Visible=False` by default. Then add this `UserControl` in an `ItemTemplate` to the second column. Handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `DropDownList`. Use `ddl.NamingContainer` to get the `GridViewRow` and `row.FindControl("UserControlD")` to find the usercontol in the row. Provide a property or method in the control which you can use to control which controls should be visible. Properties return the values( `SelectedValue` or  `Text`) if you want to reterieve them later.

Comment: You can record the control added the second column in a collection. The collection should be an instance variable/property defined in the code behind. You can then access the value entered by the user by referencing the controls in the collection.

Comment: @HashPsi: all objects are disposed at the end of the page's current liefecycle.

Comment: Really. Need to see your code here, the world of Dynamic controls is fun enough on it's own but the fun doubles when you start sticking them in GridViews. One option would be to use a HiddenField to record your data for the postback.

Comment: @TimSchmelter As long as the objects are rebuilt in the load phase with the same IDs, the values will be populated based on the data posted from the form

Comment: As mason mentioned, some markup code would be a big help. 

What about if assigned each element a class so you can reference it by the click/change event ($('.classname').click) and move the values stored in HTML data elements around (themselves loaded in code behind on the OnItemDataBound event),

Comment: Why an additional collection at all? Just make the controls visible that you want to show, the rest is stored automatically in ViewState. Invisible controls aren't even rendered as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code :
ASPX Page :

```
<asp:GridView ID="CRFormGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                OnRowDataBound="CRFormGridView_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="25" ClientIDMode="Static" OnDataBound="CRFormGridView_DataBound">

                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CRListID" HeaderText="CR List ID" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Change Type">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtpnlChangeType" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList Width="150" runat="server" ID="ddlChangeType" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChangeType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Update Offer" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Add Component" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Cancel Component" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Update Request" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Add Request" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Cancel Request" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Change Sub Type">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtpnlChangeSubType" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList Width="150" runat="server" ID="ddlChangeSubType" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChangeSubType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Request/Comments">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtpnlDynamicControl" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placehldrDynamicCnrtl" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnPreRender="placehldrDynamicCnrtl_PreRender"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Cs Page Code :

```
  protected void ddlChangeType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddlChangeType = (DropDownList)sender;
            GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)ddlChangeType.NamingContainer;
            DropDownList ddlChangeSubType = currentRow.FindControl("ddlChangeSubType") as DropDownList;

            object objControl;

            if (ddlChangeSubType != null && currentRow != null && ddlChangeType != null)
            {
                ddlChangeSubType.DataTextField = "Desc";
                ddlChangeSubType.DataValueField = "ID";
                ddlChangeSubType.DataSource = setChangeSubType(ddlChangeType.SelectedValue);
                ddlChangeSubType.DataBind();

                if (Session["DynamicControls"] != null)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < CRFormGridView.Rows.Count; y++)
                    {
                        if (((Dictionary<int, object>)Session["DynamicControls"]).TryGetValue(y, out objControl))
                        {
                            if (currentRow.RowIndex == y)
                                objControlsDict.Remove(y);
                            else
                                objControlsDict.Add(y, objControl);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Session.Add("DynamicControls", objControlsDict);
            }

        }

        protected void ddlChangeSubType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddlChangeSubType = (DropDownList)sender;
            GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)ddlChangeSubType.NamingContainer;
            DropDownList ddlChangeType = currentRow.FindControl("ddlChangeType") as DropDownList;
            //TextBox txt = currentRow.FindControl("txt") as TextBox;

            PlaceHolder placehldr = currentRow.FindControl("placehldrDynamicCnrtl") as PlaceHolder;

            object objControl;

            rowIndex = currentRow.RowIndex;
            if (Session["DynamicControls"] != null)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < CRFormGridView.Rows.Count; y++)
                {
                    if (((Dictionary<int, object>)Session["DynamicControls"]).TryGetValue(y, out objControl))
                    {
                        objControlsDict.Add(y, objControl);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (ddlChangeSubType != null && currentRow != null && ddlChangeSubType != null)
            {
                switch (ddlChangeType.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "UPDATE OFFER":
                        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
                        txtBox.Text = "Text Box Added";
                        txtBox.ID = "txt";
                        txtBox.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
                        txtBox.EnableViewState = true;
                        placehldr.Controls.Add(txtBox);
                        if (objControlsDict.ContainsKey(rowIndex))
                            objControlsDict.Remove(rowIndex);
                        objControlsDict.Add(rowIndex, txtBox);
                        break;

                    case "ADD COMPONENT":
                        Label lbl = new Label();
                        lbl.Text = "Label Added";
                        lbl.ID = "lbl";
                        lbl.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
                        lbl.EnableViewState = true;
                        placehldr.Controls.Add(lbl);
                        if (objControlsDict.ContainsKey(rowIndex))
                            objControlsDict.Remove(rowIndex);
                        objControlsDict.Add(rowIndex, lbl);
                        break;

                    case "UPDATE REQUEST":
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                Session.Add("DynamicControls", objControlsDict);
            }
        }


 protected void placehldrDynamicCnrtl_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    PlaceHolder placeHldr = (PlaceHolder)sender;
                    GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)placeHldr.NamingContainer;

                    objControlsDict = (Dictionary<int, object>)Session["DynamicControls"];
                    if (objControlsDict != null)
                    {
                        if (objControlsDict.ContainsKey(count) && objControlsDict[count] is TextBox)
                        {
                            TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)objControlsDict[count];
                            txtBox.Text = "Text Box Added";
                            txtBox.ID = "txt";
                            txtBox.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
                            txtBox.EnableViewState = true;
                            ((PlaceHolder)this.CRFormGridView.Rows[count].Cells[3].FindControl(
                                "placehldrDynamicCnrtl")).Controls.Add(txtBox);
                        }

                        if (objControlsDict.ContainsKey(count) && objControlsDict[count] is Label)
                        {
                            Label lbl = (Label)objControlsDict[count];
                            lbl.Text = "Label Added";
                            lbl.ID = "lbl";
                            lbl.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
                            lbl.EnableViewState = true;
                            ((PlaceHolder)this.CRFormGridView.Rows[count].Cells[3].FindControl(
                                "placehldrDynamicCnrtl")).Controls.Add(lbl);
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception es)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```